# onclick img in umbraco 7 disappears on save

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco

When I try to add this:

```
<div class="big-ass-div"><img src="/media/1064/non-rolled-over.png" 
   onmouseover="this.src='/media/1065/Rolled-over.png'" 
   onmouseout="this.src='/media/1064/non-rolled-over.png'" alt="" width="664" height="467"   
   />
</div>
```

, to my Content Source code in Umbraco 7, the `onclick` will be removed when I press Save. But the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` actions work just fine.

Any reason for this, and any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the TinyMCE plugin is stripping the onclick event from your HTML. There is a config file for the TinyMCE plugin in the /config folder. I think it's called TinyMCEConfig.config. There's a section in there for valid elements, make sure that onclick is  in the list of allowed attributes.